GNU GRUB Bash screen
I'm not an Ubuntu expert and did a lot of research to fix the problem that I have. When I start my laptop it gets stuck at the GNU Grub Bash screen. When I run the commands:
set root=(hd0,gpt3)
linux /vmlinuz... root=/dev/sda3 ro
initrd /initrd.img....
boot

Ubuntu does boot, but when I restart the system, it goes back to the GNU Grub Bash screen.
I also tried Boot-Repair on a live USB and it didn't fix the issue. The Boot-Repair summary is here.
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

/dev/sdb (/dev/sda) has unknown type. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
sda3,
using the following options:  sda2/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed:  unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

rm /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Mount /dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda3/boot/efi

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/sda3 ======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12-1ubuntu7
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-76-generic
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 efibootmgr -v (filtered) before grub install
BootCurrent: 000F
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 000F,0010,000D,000E,000B
Boot000B* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)414d474f414d4e4fb1000000010000006f004d0041005400530048004900540041004400560044002d00520041004d00200055004a003800430032002000530000000501090003000000007fff040002010c00d041030a0000000001010600021f03120a000200ffff00007fff040001043e00ef47642dc93ba041ac194d51d01b4ce65200480033003300200020003100350033003100350034002000200020002000200020002000200000007fff0400414d424f
Boot000D* Ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,423bddab-724f-434c-9be6-db8c76b99e1a,0x1000,0x100800)/File(EFIubuntugrubx64.efi)
Boot000E* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,423bddab-724f-434c-9be6-db8c76b99e1a,0x1000,0x100800)/File(EFIUbuntugrubx64.efi)
Boot000F* UEFI: General 5.00    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x14eb2669,0x23c,0x2130)AMBO
Boot0010* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)414d474f414d4e4f87000000010000005b00470065006e006500720061006c00200035002e003000300000000501090002000000007fff040002010c00d041030a000000000101060000140305060001007fff040001042e00ef47642dc93ba041ac194d51d01b4ce6470065006e006500720061006c00200035002e003000300000007fff0400414d424f

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 uname -r
5.15.0-76-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sda2
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda3/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda3/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/sda3/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda3/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 efibootmgr -v (filtered) after grub install
BootCurrent: 000F
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 000F,0010,000D,000E,000B
Boot000B* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)414d474f414d4e4fb1000000010000006f004d0041005400530048004900540041004400560044002d00520041004d00200055004a003800430032002000530000000501090003000000007fff040002010c00d041030a0000000001010600021f03120a000200ffff00007fff040001043e00ef47642dc93ba041ac194d51d01b4ce65200480033003300200020003100350033003100350034002000200020002000200020002000200000007fff0400414d424f
Boot000D* Ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,423bddab-724f-434c-9be6-db8c76b99e1a,0x1000,0x100800)/File(EFIubuntugrubx64.efi)
Boot000E* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,423bddab-724f-434c-9be6-db8c76b99e1a,0x1000,0x100800)/File(EFIUbuntugrubx64.efi)
Boot000F* UEFI: General 5.00    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x14eb2669,0x23c,0x2130)AMBO
Boot0010* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)414d474f414d4e4f87000000010000005b00470065006e006500720061006c00200035002e003000300000000501090002000000007fff040002010c00d041030a000000000101060000140305060001007fff040001042e00ef47642dc93ba041ac194d51d01b4ce6470065006e006500720061006c00200035002e003000300000007fff0400414d424f
Warning: NVram was not modified.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (sda2/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt3)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdc: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdc: /dev/sdc already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on sda3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.2, victoria, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: K46CB.207(4.6) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 000F
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 000F,0010,000D,000E,000B
Boot000B* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.M.A.T.S.H.I.T.A.D.V.D.-.R.A.M. .U.J.8.C.2. .S....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.R.H.3.3. . .1.5.3.1.5.4. . . . . . . . ......AMBO
Boot000D* Ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,423bddab-724f-434c-9be6-db8c76b99e1a,0x1000,0x100800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
Boot000E* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,423bddab-724f-434c-9be6-db8c76b99e1a,0x1000,0x100800)/File(EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
Boot000F* UEFI: General 5.00    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x14eb2669,0x23c,0x2130)AMBO
Boot0010* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........[.G.e.n.e.r.a.l. .5...0.0....................A..........................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.G.e.n.e.r.a.l. .5...0.0......AMBO

66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   sda2/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   sda2/BOOT/bootx64.efi
39bc76ff6662f4fbe9aa116e4c997b41   sda2/BOOT/fbx64.efi
4ba5a5aad43c197e9fb58b76b404d287   sda2/BOOT/mmx64.efi
66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   sda2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4ba5a5aad43c197e9fb58b76b404d287   sda2/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   sda2/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sdb : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda3    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sdb : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, 

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sdb : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk identifier: 3F013A57-F4BA-43DF-A34A-DB039E3C8D1D
       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
sda2     4096   1054719   1050624   513M EFI System
sda3  1054720 937701375 936646656 446.6G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 20.97 GiB, 22515204096 bytes, 43975008 sectors
Disk identifier: 97358BEB-3794-43A3-BCF4-53CDFFC98F27
Disk sdc: 3.75 GiB, 4027580416 bytes, 7866368 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x14eb2669
     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
sdc1  *          0 5138431 5138432  2.5G  0 Empty
sdc2           572    9067    8496  4.1M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sdc3       5140480 7866367 2725888  1.3G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:480GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA WD Green 2.5 480:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:540MB:538MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
3:540MB:480GB:480GB:ext4::;
sdb:22.5GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA SG9MSM6D024GPM00:;
sdc:4028MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:General :;
2:293kB:4643kB:4350kB:::esp;
3:2632MB:4028MB:1396MB:ext4::;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sdb: 0.02MiB:21472MiB:21472MiB
sdc: 4.43MiB:2510MiB:2506MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                              
├─sda1                                               9652a2f7-ce9b-4001-b267-e0b1d355ed17                        
├─sda2 vfat     F1B8-5A45                            423bddab-724f-434c-9be6-db8c76b99e1a                        EFI System Partition
└─sda3 ext4     14d6a7ca-a5a1-42e4-a41c-05cad45fcc70 ce763b60-1d29-4b34-ae07-12710de17181                        
sdb                                                                                                              
sdc    iso9660  2023-12-23-05-05-55-00                                                    Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
├─sdc1 iso9660  2023-12-23-05-05-55-00               14eb2669-01                          Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 
├─sdc2 vfat     8D6C-A9F8                            14eb2669-02                          ESP                    
└─sdc3 ext4     aa494a2c-4e64-4205-87f8-dd354558a745 14eb2669-03                          writable               

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                             Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                                                   501.7M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3                                                   191.1G  51% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sdc1                                                        0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda2                                                   vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda3                                                   ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdc1                                                   iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

===================== sda2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 14d6a7ca-a5a1-42e4-a41c-05cad45fcc70 root hd0,gpt3 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

========================== sda3/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=14d6a7ca-a5a1-42e4-a41c-05cad45fcc70 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=F1B8-5A45  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
devpts /dev/pts devpts defaults 0 0

======================= sda3/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda3: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  24.045104980 = 25.818234880   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 272.477794647 = 292.570804224  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 207.784175873 = 223.106560000  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic                  2
 272.477794647 = 292.570804224  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-49-generic                  2
 207.784175873 = 223.106560000  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 308.736057281 = 331.502817280  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic               8
 308.736057281 = 331.502817280  boot/initrd.img.old                            8

===================== sda3: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  83 Nov 28 22:53 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 103 Nov 28 22:53 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 212 Nov 28 22:49 40_custom
sprunge.us ko ()

Please, how can I fix the access to Grub? Thank you!

I am also not an expert.
Looking at you boot repair information I believe that the USB device is booted in MBR mode.
Boot000F* UEFI: General 5.00    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x14eb2669,0x23c,0x2130)AMBO 

Grub cannot install because grub-install cannot add itself to the EFI boot menu unless the system has already booted in EFI mode. (The "EFI variables" are impossible to access in BIOS mode.)
https://superuser.com/questions/764799/how-to-create-an-efi-system-partition
However, you can boot your system manually as you have described. If you do this and then attempt to do what the boot repair was doing manually it should work. So boot manually as you did, run a gnome-terminal and run the following: -
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /sda

sudo update-grub

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/grub-efi-reinstall
and then just reboot and, hopefully it will boot normally.
Good luck.
